# isStraight evaluation function

Tags: javascript, playing-cards, weekend-challenge

The context is Weekend Challenge #2 (Poker hand evaluation).

```
Hand.prototype.isStraight = function()
{
  for( var i = 1 ; i < this.cards.length ; i++ )
    if( this.cards[i].value + 1 != this.cards[i-1].value )
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

`cards` is an array with card objects `{ suit : "x" , value : "0->12" }`.  The cards are sorted during the creation of the hand.

My approach to detect straightness seems like the hard way.  Can anyone suggest something else?

Okay, Poker is tough.  I will revise this question once I have my new `isStraight`.

Comment: Ugh. You have no idea how much I wish it were *that* simple.

Comment: Are the cards guaranteed to be maintained as sorted?

Comment: Indeed the straight seems to be one of the hardest things about this week's challenge. I like your approach but remember that Ace can be used as both `1` and `14` in a straight (Ace - 5 and 10 - Ace). Also, why are you starting the loop at `i = 1` when arrays indexes tends to be 0-based?

Comment: How many cards do you have in `this.cards`? Are you assuming a 5-card hand? Can you tell 5 consecutive cards in a 7-card hand? What if you have only 3 cards, is that a straight? As @SimonAndréForsberg has mentioned, what about aces low / aces high?

Comment: @retailcoder Let's not make it too complicated for now. If he is assuming a 5-card hand, that's acceptable IMO :P

Comment: Although I have to add: If you don't want to handle both the low & high ace case, that's OK for now.

Comment: Wait a minute, a straight is 5 cards, even if your hand has 7 cards ?

Comment: @tomdemuyt that's what makes it a PITA!!

Comment: @tomdemuyt Depends on if you're playing Texas Hold 'em or one of the million other possible poker variations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that hard.

Instead of sorting the cards, looping over them and skipping double results, let's convert them to a more useful format:

```
var bitmap = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
{
    var value = cards[i].value;

    // set i+1 bit in the bitmap
    bitmap |= 1 << (value + 1);

    // if it's an ace, also set the low bit
    if(value === 12)
        bitmap |= 1;
}
```

Now, if there's a card of value `i` in your hand, the `i+1` bit will be set in the bitmap. An Ace is treated as two cards with values 13 and 0.
Next, we scan the bitmap for 5 consecutive bits set, which is equivalent to 31 (`1 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 16`). We start with the highest straight, which is 9.
The lowest straight is 0, if there is no straight `i` is -1.

```
for(var i = 10; i--; )
{
    if((bitmap & 31 << i) === (31 << i))
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

The method works for games with more than 5 cards. Note that in any variant of Poker, 5 cards make a hand, so even in Omaha with 9 cards, 5 cards give you a straight.

**Note:** The method is roughly equivalent to creating a set (and checking for 5 consecutive elements). As you can see, with bit-wise operators it is much simpler to check for 5 consecutive cards.

**Another note:** There's a harder-to-understand but slightly faster method for testing a straight given the bitmap. I might add it later, but for now I think this method hard enough to understand for beginners.